# I cant update my component state.. Do somebody understand how it fix?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I cant understand why my renderMovies() function dont wanna update my component state.data and i cant render component on my screen ?!
Everithing goes ok until renderMovies function.. I think this.setState(newState) in my fetchPostData function is working incorrect... Do somebody know how to fix it? I tried different ways but i cant solve this issue.

```
class Movies extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { data: {}}

        this.fetchPostData = this.fetchPostData.bind(this)
        this.renderMovies = this.renderMovies.bind(this)
        this.populatePageAfterFetch = this.populatePageAfterFetch.bind(this)

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPostData()
    }

    fetchPostData() {
        fetch(`http://localhost/reacttest/wp-json/wp/v2/movies?per_page=100`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(myJSON => {
                let objLength = Object.keys(myJSON).length
                let newState = this.state;

                for (let i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
                    let objKey = Object.values(myJSON)[i].title.rendered;
                    // console.log(objKey)
                    let currentMovie = newState.data[objKey];


                    currentMovie = {};
                    currentMovie.name = Object.values(myJSON)[i].title.rendered;

                    currentMovie.description = Object.values(myJSON)[i].content.rendered;

                    currentMovie.featured_image = Object.values(myJSON)[i]['featured_image_url'];

                    currentMovie.genre = Object.values(myJSON)[i]['genre'];

                }

                this.setState(newState)
            })
    }

    renderMovies() {
        if(this.state.data) {
            const moviesArray = Object.values(this.state.data)
            console.log(moviesArray)
            return Object.values(moviesArray).map((movie, index) => this.populatePageAfterFetch(movie, index))
        }
    }

    populatePageAfterFetch(movie, index) {
        if (this.state.data) {

            return (
                <div key={index} index={index}>
                    <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
                    <h3>{movie.genre}</h3>
                    <p>{movie.description}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Movies</h1>
                <div>{this.renderMovies()}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When i try to console.log(moviesArray) it show me:

[image]

Comment: are you getting values if you log 'newState' just before the line 'this.setState(newState)'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You save current state into a variable named `newState`, never update it, and then save the same object reference back into state. React state never really updates.

```
let newState = this.state;

for (let i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
  ...
}

this.setState(newState);
```

Additionally you mutate state

```
let currentMovie = newState.data[objKey];
currentMovie = {};
```

But this doesn't work either since initial state is an empty object so `newState.data[objKey]` is aways undefined. (*so nothing is ever actually mutated*)

## Solution

It appears as though you intended to map the `myJSON` data/values into movie objects to update `this.state.data`. May I suggest this solution. The key is to *always* create new object references for any object you update.

```
fetchPostData() {
  fetch(`http://localhost/reacttest/wp-json/wp/v2/movies?per_page=100`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJSON => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        // array::reduce over the JSON values
        data: Object.values(myJSON).reduce((movies, movie) => {
          // compute movie key
          const name = movie.title.rendered;

          return {
            ...movies,
            [name]: {
              ...movies[name], // copy any existing movie properties
              // merge in new/updated properties
              name,
              description: movie.content.rendered,
              featured_image: movie.featured_image_url,
              genre: movie.genre,
            },
          }
        }, { ...prevState.data }) // use previous state as initial value for reduce
      }))
    })
}
```